# Improved QML Settings

Tags: c++, qt, qml

`Qt.labs.settings 1.0` module from `QtDeclarative` (depricated) allows to use `QSettings` to make some of *QML* properties persistent. It is quite outdated and inconvenient. E.g. to get access to value `x` in group `a` and to value `y` in subgroup `b` of group `a` one need to specify full path in second case:

```
Settings {
    category: "a"
    property int x
}
Settings {
    category: "a/b"
    property int y
}
```

For deeper nesting it require more boilerplate code.

It is not big deal, but it would be better, if tree structure of `QSettings` would be explicitly exposed in *QML*:

```
Settings {
    prefix: "a"
    property int x
    SettingsGroup {
        prefix: "b"
        property int y
    }
}
```

To meet these ideas I reinvent `Settings` and `SettingsGroup` QML types. Both of them have (maybe empty) property `prefix` to specify (sub)group name. `Settings` default value is *QML* `list` of `SettingsGroup`. `SettingsGroup` default value is *QML* `list` of `SettingsGroup`.

After some property of the "settings tree" is changed, notification signal triggers timer and after a period of time (default 500 ms) all values of changed properties are flushed on `QSettings`' storage if no new property changing notification signal is emitted. This allows to perform batching of save operation in case of changing a multiple of mutually dependent *QML* properties. On destruction all values of changed properties are also flushed.

```
// settings.hpp
#pragma once

#include <QtQml>

class SettingsGroup
        : public QObject
{

    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString prefix MEMBER prefix NOTIFY prefixChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty< SettingsGroup > groups READ getGroups)

    Q_CLASSINFO("DefaultProperty", "groups")

public :

    explicit SettingsGroup(QObject * const root = Q_NULLPTR);

    ~SettingsGroup() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE Q_DECL_EQ_DEFAULT;

    QQmlListProperty< SettingsGroup > getGroups();

Q_SIGNALS :

    void prefixChanged(QString prefix);

private :

    QHash< int, const char * > propertyNames;
    QHash< const char *, QVariant > changedProperties; // it is essential to save property value, because in destructor property("propertyName") became null

protected :

    void init(QSettings & settings, QTimer * const timer);

    void store(QSettings & settings);

    void invalidate();

private Q_SLOTS :

    void onPropertyChanged();

private :

    QString prefix;
    QVector< SettingsGroup * > groups;

};

class Settings
        : public SettingsGroup
        , public QQmlParserStatus
{

    Q_OBJECT

    Q_INTERFACES(QQmlParserStatus)

public :

    explicit Settings(QObject * const parent = Q_NULLPTR);

    ~Settings() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

private :

    void classBegin() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    void componentComplete() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

    QSettings settings;

};

//settings.cpp
#include "settings.hpp"

SettingsGroup::SettingsGroup(QObject * const parent)
    : QObject{parent}
{ ; }

QQmlListProperty< SettingsGroup > SettingsGroup::getGroups()
{
    using SettingsList = QQmlListProperty< SettingsGroup >;
    const SettingsList::AppendFunction appendFunction = [] (SettingsList * listProperty, SettingsGroup * value)
    {
        const auto self = qobject_cast< SettingsGroup * >(listProperty->object);
        Q_ASSERT(self);
        if (qobject_cast< Settings * >(self)) {
            return;
        }
    #ifdef QT_DEBUG
            const auto prefix = value->property("prefix");
            for (const auto group : self->groups) {
                if (group->property("prefix") == prefix) {
                    QQmlError error;
                    error.setMessageType(QtWarningMsg);
                    error.setUrl(QString::fromLatin1(Q_FUNC_INFO));
                    error.setObject(value);
                    error.setDescription(tr("Group with prefix '%1' is already listed in '%2'").arg(prefix.toString(), self->prefix));
                    qmlWarning(self, error);
                }
            }
    #endif
        self->groups.append(value);
    };
    const SettingsList::CountFunction countFunction = [] (SettingsList * listProperty) -> int
    {
        const auto self = qobject_cast< SettingsGroup * >(listProperty->object);
        Q_ASSERT(self);
        return self->groups.count();
    };
    const SettingsList::AtFunction atFunction = [] (SettingsList * listProperty, int index) -> SettingsGroup *
    {
        const auto self = qobject_cast< SettingsGroup * >(listProperty->object);
        Q_ASSERT(self);
        return self->groups.at(index);
    };
    const SettingsList::ClearFunction clearFunction = [] (SettingsList * listProperty)
    {
        const auto self = qobject_cast< SettingsGroup * >(listProperty->object);
        Q_ASSERT(self);
        self->groups.clear();
    };
    return {this, Q_NULLPTR, appendFunction, countFunction, atFunction, clearFunction};
}

void SettingsGroup::init(QSettings & settings, QTimer * const timer)
{
    if (!prefix.isEmpty()) {
        settings.beginGroup(prefix);
    }
    {
        const auto onPrefixChanged = [this, timer]
        {
            invalidate();
            timer->start();
        };
        connect(this, &SettingsGroup::prefixChanged, timer, onPrefixChanged);
        static const int offset = staticMetaObject.propertyCount();
        const auto mo = metaObject();
        const int count = mo->propertyCount();
        for (int i = offset; i < count; ++i) {
            const auto mp = mo->property(i);
            auto oldValue = mp.read(this);
            if (mp.userType() == qMetaTypeId< QJSValue >()) {
                oldValue = oldValue.value< QJSValue >().toVariant();
            }
            const auto propertyName = QString::fromLatin1(mp.name());
            if (settings.contains(propertyName)) {
                const auto newValue = settings.value(propertyName, oldValue);
                if (!newValue.isNull() && (!oldValue.isValid() || newValue.canConvert(oldValue.type())) && (oldValue != newValue)) {
                    if (!mp.write(this, newValue)) {
                        settings.setValue(propertyName, oldValue); // force renew the type of saved value
                    }
                }
            } else {
                settings.setValue(propertyName, oldValue);
            }
            if (mp.hasNotifySignal()) {
                const int signalIndex = mp.notifySignalIndex();
                if (!propertyNames.contains(signalIndex)) {
                    propertyNames.insert(signalIndex, mp.name());
                    static const int onPropertyChangedIndex = staticMetaObject.indexOfSlot("onPropertyChanged()");
                    QMetaObject::connect(this, signalIndex, this, onPropertyChangedIndex);
                    static const int timerStartIndex = timer->staticMetaObject.indexOfSlot("start()");
                    QMetaObject::connect(this, signalIndex, timer, timerStartIndex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (const auto group : groups) {
        group->init(settings, timer);
    }
    if (!prefix.isEmpty()) {
        settings.endGroup();
    }
}

void SettingsGroup::store(QSettings & settings)
{
    if (!prefix.isEmpty()) {
        settings.beginGroup(prefix);
    }
    if (!changedProperties.isEmpty()) {
        QHashIterator changedProperty{changedProperties};
        while (changedProperty.hasNext()) {
            changedProperty.next();
            settings.setValue(QString::fromLatin1(changedProperty.key()), changedProperty.value());
        }
        changedProperties.clear();
    }
    for (const auto group : groups) {
        group->store(settings);
    }
    if (!prefix.isEmpty()) {
        settings.endGroup();
    }
}

void SettingsGroup::invalidate()
{
    for (const auto & propertyName : propertyNames) {
        changedProperties.insert(propertyName, property(propertyName));
    }
    for (const auto group : groups) {
        group->invalidate();
    }
}

void SettingsGroup::onPropertyChanged()
{
    Q_ASSERT(sender() == this);
    const int signalIndex = senderSignalIndex();
    Q_ASSERT(!(signalIndex < 0));
    Q_ASSERT(propertyNames.contains(signalIndex));
    const auto propertyName = propertyNames[signalIndex];
    changedProperties.insert(propertyName, property(propertyName));
}

Settings::Settings(QObject * const parent)
    : SettingsGroup{parent}
{ ; }

Settings::~Settings()
{
    store(settings);
}

void Settings::classBegin()
{
    // no op
}

void Settings::componentComplete()
{
    const auto timer = ::new QTimer{this};
    Q_CHECK_PTR(timer);
    timer->setSingleShot(true);
    timer->setInterval(settings.value("saveDelay", 500).toInt());
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [this] { store(settings); settings.sync(); });
    init(settings, timer);
    settings.sync();
}
```

It is possible to further improve `Settings` type to use not only default-constructed `QSettings` object (in fact it was a main goal). It seems, that it is currently impossible to correctly add new `SettingsGroup` objects into `list` default properties of existent `Settings`/`SettingsGroup` objects dynamically.

What are architectural misconceptions or style errors? Can they
 be improved?

(tested on Qt 5.9.1, g++ (Ubuntu 7.1.0-5ubuntu2~16.04) 7.1.0)